# Trying to figure out days between every event based on user id in excel

Tags: excel

Trying to figure out the number of days for every user's play event with respect to its first event . i.e (t1-f), (t2-f) etc. for every user id

Input

```
     date        id     event   changepoint of user id
    1/25/2019   10002   Play    f
    1/25/2019   10002   Play    t
    1/1/2019    10004   Play    f
    1/30/2019   10012   Play    f
    1/30/2019   10012   Play    t
    2/13/2019   10012   Play    t
    1/19/2019   10013   Play    f
    1/19/2019   10013   Play    t
    1/19/2019   10013   Play    t
    1/21/2019   10013   Play    t
    2/3/2019    10019   Play    f
    2/3/2019    10019   Play    t
```

With the formula that i am using , i am just getting difference of days between current and previous day.

Expected output

```
date         id     event   cp  days
1/25/2019   10002   Play    f   0
1/25/2019   10002   Play    t   0  (t-f)
1/1/2019    10004   Play    f   0
1/30/2019   10012   Play    f   0
1/30/2019   10012   Play    t   0  (t-f)
2/13/2019   10012   Play    t   14 (t-f)
1/19/2019   10013   Play    f   0
1/19/2019   10013   Play    t   0  (t-f)
1/19/2019   10013   Play    t   0  (t-f)
1/21/2019   10013   Play    t   2  (t-f)
2/3/2019    10019   Play    f   0  (t-f)
2/3/2019    10019   Play    t   0  (t-f)
```

Comment: `MAXIF(ID) - MINIF(ID)` will work, but depending on your version of excel, these formulas may not be available to you

Comment: difference in date is what i am trying to figure out. the formula u suggested , i think will calculate the difference in id's

Comment: `=MAXIFS(Date Column, ID Column, ID) - MINIFS(Date Column, ID Column, ID)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making a few assumptions here:

- That the data is always sorted by date and id,
- That the id does not appear again after the id changed (e.g. 10002 does not appear again after ID 10019),
- `f` always comes before `t` and the last `t` is where the difference is required.

---

```
=IF(B2<>B3,IF(MIN(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,D:D,"t"),COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,D:D,"f"))=0,0,MAXIFS($A:$A,$D:$D,"t",$B:$B,$B2)-MINIFS($A:$A,$D:$D,"f",$B:$B,$B2)),0)
```

[image]

`MIN(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,D:D,"t"),COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,D:D,"f"))=0` this part makes sure there is at least 1 `t` and 1 `f` in the data for the calculation to take place. If there is only `f`, `MAXIFS` will return 0 and `MINIFS` will return the date `f` occurred, which will result in a big negative value.

`MAXIFS($A:$A,$D:$D,"t",$B:$B,$B2)-MINIFS($A:$A,$D:$D,"f",$B:$B,$B2)` gives the difference in days.

`IF(B2<>B3, ... , 0)` checks if the next ID is different, and if it is the same, just put 0 (otherwise the difference in days will appear in every row for the ID)

---

If your excel doesn't support `MINIFS` and `MAXIFS`, you will have to use the longer array formula (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to use it properly. You know you did it properly if Excel put braces around the formula):

```
=IF(B2<>B3,IF(MIN(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,D:D,"t"),COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,D:D,"f"))=0,0,MAX(IF(($D:$D="t")*($B:$B=$B2),$A:$A))-MIN(IF(($D:$D="f")*($B:$B=$B2),$A:$A))),0)
```

[image]

---

After the comments, I realise I have misunderstood the problem. Here's a new formula that should be more to what you expected:

```
=IF(D2="t",IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,D:D,"t")=0,0,A2-SUMIFS($A:$A,$D:$D,"f",$B:$B,$B2)),0)
```

[image]

Comment: @Nrj Then it means that your Excel version doesn't support `MAXIFS` and `MINIFS`... I will update my answer.

Comment: Really appreciate the work and efforts u put in. Thank u so much

Comment: https://ibb.co/v17YL6P . Formula works but not exactly getting the expected results for some id's

Comment: i am working on data where i want to find out every user's difference of number of days after their first videoplay event.

Comment: @Nrj Ok, I guess I misunderstood the original question. I'm working on a new formula, which actually seems like it'll be simpler. Does a particular ID always have only one `f`?

Comment: yes.. the first event will always start with f .. that is the change point of every user id

Comment: @Nrj Edited answer, see the last part